# Critical values of sine function, when undefined

Tags: calculus

This may be a  beginner question, but I really want to understand this good and thorough.

I have this sine function, withing the interval $-3 ≤ x ≤ 3$

$$f(x)=\frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\sin(2\pi x)}$$

My question is regarding local maximum and minimum values wich i assume this function does not have, as all $f'(x)=0$ are undefined? In the same manner this function would also not have a horizontal tangent?

(as far as i understand its possible to transform the function using trig identities, but the questions above is regarding the function in it's original form.)

Would be really greatful for any help.

Comment: Proofread please.

Comment: The sine duplication formula helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\sin(2\pi x)=2\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x).$ Hence, at every point $x\in[-3,3]$ *at which* $f(x)$ *exists*, we have $$f(x)=\frac1{2\cos(\pi x)}.$$ The function $\frac1{2\cos(\pi x)}$ has local maxima and minima, but none of them are in the domain of $f,$ so you are correct!

Comment: Yes I am aware of the trig identity transformation.
Just to follow up your answer..

how can the function as you say, have local max min, when they are out of the domain of f
is this not the same, as to say that the function has no maxima and minima?

Comment: Because the function $g(x)=\frac1{2\cos(\pi x)}$ is not the same as $f(x),$ though the two functions agree at every point of the domain of $f.$ The function $g(x)$ has a *strictly larger* domain, which includes some integers, at which $g(x)$ has local extrema. At all other points of the domain of $g(x),$ it has a positive or negative derivative. Consequently, $f(x)$ *always* has a positive or negative derivative, so cannot have any local extrema. Does that make sense?

Comment: Your explanation makes perfect sense =)

As you can tell im pretty new to calculus, and i guess this is a textbook problem.. I just thought that any trig identity would keep the orgnal function 100% intact, but basically the "algebraic" conversion is not 100% between f(x) and g(x)?

Really appreciate your answers

Comment: You're very welcome. It's good to keep in mind that an identity is an equation that holds wherever *both sides are defined*. So, for example, $\ln(-x)=\sqrt x$ is a real identity, despite the fact that it's never true, since the left side is only defined on the negative reals, while the right side is only defined on the nonnegative reals!

Comment: So basically trig identities etc are not to be viewed in the same "basic" sense as ordinary equations?

Any chance you could provide more info on this? Link or so..
have to ponder upon your example =) still a rookie in this

Comment: Identities are a special type of equation. With equations in general, the solution set could be any subset of the common domain of the left and right sides. For (a contrived) example, let $\chi_A(x)$ be the indicator function of some subset $A$ of $\Bbb R.$ Then the equation $$\chi_A(x)=1$$ holds precisely when $x\in A,$ though both sides of the equation are defined on the whole real line.

Comment: Trig identities are particularly nice, because they tend to hold "almost everywhere."